# OverGrive not launching

Tags: python, google

I installed OverGrive and it worked fine for a few days before it suddenly stopped launching. I've tried a few things, including reinstalling `pip`, `python`, etc.

When I run:

```
python /opt/thefanclub/overgrive/overgrive
```

I get:

```
Google Drive for Linux   version 3.1.9 beta

   by The Fan Club - Copyright (c) 2014-2016   
           http://www.thefanclub.co.za         

[INFO] Linux-4.4.0-22-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 
[INFO]Desktop : ubuntu 
[CONFIG] Loading User Settings GUI mode 
[CONFIG] Auto Sync : True 
[CONFIG] Convert Google Docs : False 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "overgrive.py", line 5952, in <module>
  StopIteration
```

Comment: Is there more to that error? It seems to be missing the actual reason.

Comment: Could you please open `overgrive.py` in a text editor and edit your question  to include line 5952 of that file? That may give clues as to what's happening.

Comment: Nick, that file does not have that many lines

Answer (score 2):

Update to the [latest version](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive) from our website. Issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you. Just installed latest version and it seems to work.